# Read the Penn TreeBank into a PCFG

Tags: nlp

I'm looking for a program for library that can take as input the Wall Street Journal (WSJ) section of the Penn TreeBank (PTB), and output the corresponding Probabilistic Context-Free Grammars (PCFGs).

If possible:

- option to get a lexicalized PCFG
- Python/Java/C++
- runs on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate or Ubuntu

The Penn TreeBank consists of thousand of annotated sentences. Below are 3 of them:

```
( (S 
    (NP-SBJ 
      (NP (NNP Pierre) (NNP Vinken) )
      (, ,) 
      (ADJP 
        (NP (CD 61) (NNS years) )
        (JJ old) )
      (, ,) )
    (VP (MD will) 
      (VP (VB join) 
        (NP (DT the) (NN board) )
        (PP-CLR (IN as) 
          (NP (DT a) (JJ nonexecutive) (NN director) ))
        (NP-TMP (NNP Nov.) (CD 29) )))
    (. .) ))
( (S 
    (NP-SBJ (NNP Mr.) (NNP Vinken) )
    (VP (VBZ is) 
      (NP-PRD 
        (NP (NN chairman) )
        (PP (IN of) 
          (NP 
            (NP (NNP Elsevier) (NNP N.V.) )
            (, ,) 
            (NP (DT the) (NNP Dutch) (VBG publishing) (NN group) )))))
    (. .) ))

( (S 
    (NP-SBJ-1 
      (NP (NNP Rudolph) (NNP Agnew) )
      (, ,) 
      (UCP 
        (ADJP 
          (NP (CD 55) (NNS years) )
          (JJ old) )
        (CC and) 
        (NP 
          (NP (JJ former) (NN chairman) )
          (PP (IN of) 
            (NP (NNP Consolidated) (NNP Gold) (NNP Fields) (NNP PLC) ))))
      (, ,) )
    (VP (VBD was) 
      (VP (VBN named) 
        (S 
          (NP-SBJ (-NONE- *-1) )
          (NP-PRD 
            (NP (DT a) (JJ nonexecutive) (NN director) )
            (PP (IN of) 
              (NP (DT this) (JJ British) (JJ industrial) (NN conglomerate) ))))))
    (. .) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for pythons [SciKit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) and the Natural Language Toolkit ([NLKT](http://www.nltk.org/)) as it has its own CFG and treebank modules as demonstrated [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html).

- Free
- Python
- Looks like a lot of academic work heading in the same direction using these tools.
- Multi-platform, (even Windows)!